# What is the correct way to check a link in a cucumber test?

Tags: xpath, cucumber

I have been unable to find an answer to this question. I want to write a simple step in Cucumber to check a link is present on a page and that it has the correct text and href. Something like this:

```
Then /^I see the page with link "(.*?)" to "(.*?)"$/ do |link,url|
  page.should have_xpath("//a[text()='#{link}',@href='#{url}']")
end
```

Except that doesn't work. THe xpath syntax is incorrect and I have struggled to find a good explanation of the syntax.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be:

```
page.should have_link(link, :href => url)
```

See the [capybara spec](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/spec/session/has_link_spec.rb) for details.

Comment: thanks for that. I knew there must have been a better way but have_link escaped me. Cucumber book mentions have_content but not have_link. much appreciated.

Comment: Capybara methods are not well-documented. Directly checking specs is the most reliable way to get answers to these kinds of questions.

Comment: You can get ideas from the specs but they are not comprehensive. For example, at the moment, neither the specs nor the docs tell you that `has_link?` actually searches in the text field as well the id, title, and img alt attributes. I found this out after a long debugging session that took me to [this XPath source code](https://github.com/jnicklas/xpath/blob/master/lib/xpath/html.rb#L14).

Comment: That's really unfortunate. Documentation is really important... you only notice when it's missing!

Answer (score 3):

I believe the XPath you want is

```
page.should have_xpath("//a[text()='#{link}' and @href='#{url}']")
```

I'm not familiar with Cucumber, but if it relies on Capybara, the `has_link?` alternative suggested by @shioyama is easier to read:

```
page.should have_link(link, :href => url)
```

However it's also deceptively simple. With `has_link?`, keep in mind:

- It searches on substrings (your XPath example searches on an exact match).
- It searches for "link" in the text value, but *also* in id, title, and img alt fields.
- If you specify other attributes as options, e.g. `:text` or `:class`, they will be silently ignored. You may think you are narrowing your test but you are not.

Consider the following HTML:

```
<a href="/contacts/3" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete"
   title="Delete Contact 3">Delete</a>
```

I was rather surprised to find that because `has_link?` searches for a substring of  `title`, *both* of the following conditions match that link:

```
has_link?("Contact 3", href: "/contacts/3")
has_link?("Delete", href: "/contacts/3")
```

I am currently experimenting with a custom `has_exact_link` matcher that eliminates the ambiguity by formatting the XPath explicitly. It searches for an exact match of the text value only, not a substring, and any options other than `:href` raise an error:

**spec/support/matchers.rb**

```
# Check for an <a> tag with the exact text and optional :href and  :count.
# Same param syntax as has_link, but it only matches the link's TEXT, not id,
# label, etc., and it doesn't match substrings.
def has_exact_link?(locator, options={})

  # Subtract :href, :count from array of options.keys
  # Raise error if any options remain
  raise ArgumentError.new \
    "options, if supplied, must be a hash" if !options.is_a?(Hash)
  raise ArgumentError.new \
    "has_exact_link only supports 'href' and 'count' as options" unless
    (options.keys - [:href] - [:count]).empty?
  href = options[:href]
  xpath = href ? "//a[normalize-space(text())='#{locator}' and @href='#{href}']" :
                 "//a[normalize-space(text())='#{locator}']/@href"
  # pass original options has so test results will show options if present
  # has_xpath apparently ignores :href in options but will use :count.
  has_xpath?(xpath, options)

end
```

---

**Update Sept. 19, 2012:**  added "normalize-space" to `has_exact_link` above so it will ignore leading and trailing whitespace as HTML does. This is required if, for example, the text of your link is on a different line than the `<a>` tag, e.g.

```
<a href="/contacts/3">
  Contact 3
</a>
```

It still does not match substrings. To match the above,  you must specify `has_exact_link("Contact 3")`, not just `has_exact_link("Contact")`.

---

**Update Sept. 20, 2012** Another `has_exact_link` update, above. Now it does type-checking on the `options` parameter, and handles the `:count` option as well as `:href`.

Comment: Mark Berry thanks for this... I had an issue with `has_xpath?` not accepting `href` in the options so I made the following change:

`href = options[:href]` became `href = options.delete(:href)`